# How to use CSS namespace selectors with an HTML document?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, namespaces, frontend

I have an `HTML` document that uses namespaces:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:test="http://example/test">
<head>
    <title>Selectors</title>
    <link href="selectors.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <test:p>Hello</test:p>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see in this document I defined `xmlns:test="http://example/test"` namespace and then used it here: `<test:p>Hello</test:p>`.

According to [css @namespace selector documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@namespace), in my `css` file I selected `test:p` element like so:

```
@namespace test url("http://example/test");

test|p {
    color:red;
}
```

For some reason `test:p` element is not selected. Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong and how to select elements with the appropriate namespace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use back slash to escape the colon sign:

```
test\:p {
   color:blue;
}
```

and if you use jQuery, you must use double slash

```
$('.test\\:p')
```